# Stack implementation in recursive function

Tags: recursion, f#, stack, depth-first-search, backtracking

I'm trying to implement a recursive backtracking function using depth first search and I'm stuck in a point where I need to know my previous position in a matrix.

The idea is this: I have a matrix as a 2D Array and this is my function:

Mark the current point,if the point is what I'm looking for, I set the point in the matrix as part of the solution and all the previously marked points as part of the solution as well.
Else I call the function to a valid adjacent point.

The problem is the third case: if there are no valid adjacents points, then I need to mark the point as wrong and call the function to my previous location. To do that I think I need a stack that keeps track of my previous movement but I'm having an hard time figuring out how to do so in f#.

```
let rec  solve (x,y) =

         mark (x,y)

         if (x,y) = pointimlookingfor then
           for x in 0.. array width-1 do
               for y in 0..array height-1 do
                   if Myarray.[x,y]=markedpoint then
                      Myarray.[x,y]<-partofsolution

         else if (List.isEmpty(adjacentslist) then
              Myarray.[x,y]<-wrong point
              solve (the previous visited point)

         else 
              for (adjacentpoint) in adjacentslist do
                   solve(adjacentpoint)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most functional languages, the default list type is an immutable linked-list, which you can use as a simple stack, because of its construction.

`cons` is push into stack, and `head` is pop from stack.
With that, we can write a simple stack module.

```
module Stack =
    let empty = []
    let push item stack = item::stack
    let pop = function
    | [] -> failwith "No items in stack"
    | x::xs -> xs
    let peek stack = stack |> List.tryHead
```

So,

```
Stack.empty |> Stack.push 1 |> Stack.push 2 |> Stack.pop |> Stack.pop = Stack.empty //true
```

In actual practice, instead of explicitly using functions like the above, the easiest way is to use pattern matching on some accumulator which you carry with you as you recurse/fold.

For an example, let's re-create a classic use-case for a stack - [balancing parenthesis](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/). 
Every time you encounter an open brace, you push to stack, when you encounter a closing brace, you pop from the stack, and see if it matches the last one you pushed in. If it doesn't, it's unbalanced.

```
let rec isBalanced stack = function
| '(' | '{' | '[' as opened -> opened::stack //push into stack
| ')' | '}' | ']' as closed -> 
    match stack with
    | opened::rest as all -> //pop from stack
        match opened, closed with
        | '(', ')' 
        | '{', '}' 
        | '[', ']' -> rest
        | _ -> failwith "Mismatched braces"
    | [] -> failwith "Closing before open"
| _ -> stack

"abc() { [ 1; 2; 3] }" |> Seq.fold (isBalanced) []
```

There are more concise ways to write this, but this illustrates how you can simulate a classical stack with immutable structures.

In your case, you could push an (x,y) tuple on to the stack, and let the algorithm backtrack by destructuring it: `(x,y)::tail`.